# What do we call a song or music we perform during a funeral or for a dead person?

Tags: word-request

What do we call a song or music we perform during a funeral or for a dead person? I was thinking for "funeral song", but there has to be some kind of more specific term for this. I don't mind if the answer doesn't cover all of the cases mentioned as long as it is meant to be performed during a funeral, or for a dead person.

Comment: There are several words, that a (bilingual) dictionary will show you.  Now please use your dictionary, or explain why this is impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first word that springs to my mind is ***dirge***. From [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/dirge):

> *dirge** (*n.*) a slow sad song often sung at a funeral

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/dirge) says:

> A dirge is a slow, sad song or piece of music. Dirges are sometimes performed at funerals.

Comment: Perhaps in the middle ages, but now very few funerals will employ a dirge.

Comment: @JamesK - Fair point. However, if we are going to split hairs over subtle nuances like that, I fail to see how a [bilingual dictionary](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/218856/what-do-we-call-a-song-or-music-we-perform-during-a-funeral-or-for-a-dead-person#comment418095_218856) will help solve the OP's problem.

Comment: I don't know Russian.  I can think of four words for a funeral song: "elegy", "dirge", "lament" and "threnode".  Perhaps "requiem" too.  I can use a bilingual dictionary.  I'm pretty sure that "панихида" or "элегия" or "плач" could be the word in Russian.  Some further searching suggests "плач" means "crying", and not a type of song, but "панихида" seems like a good possibility.  Now I've done the research.  OP hasn't. "Dirge" might be the answer, but "My Way" isn't a dirge.

Comment: @JamesK - I pray they won't play "My Way" at my funeral. Just sayin'.